# C - multidimensional array memory allocation based on user input

Tags: c, arrays

I have seen the following declaration of two dimensional array.

```
  int arr[][3] = { {1,2,3}, {4,5,6}};
```

My question is how can I allocate following multidimensional array in run time based on user input of first dimension?

```
   #define M 10
   #define N 15

   int arr[][M][N]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start by declaring a pointer suitable for accessing the array:

```
int (*array)[M][N];
```

Then allocate memory for the array based on the user input:

```
array = malloc(P * sizeof(*array));    // P is the value obtained from the user
```

Then use the pointer as if it was a 3D array:

```
array[x][y][z] = 42;
```

Don't forget to `free` the memory when you're done with it.

Comment: Can you please explain these lines... int(*array)[M][N] and malloc. In malloc, what is the sizeof returns? the size of whole array or the size of int pointer?

Comment: @userfirst785935 `sizeof(array)`  is the size of a pointer, but `sizeof(*array)` is the size of an array of 150 ints. So if you try `printf("%zu\n", sizeof(*array))`, the output should be 600 (assuming an `int` is 4 bytes). When you multiply the 600 by the value provided by the user, the result is the number of bytes in the whole 3D array.

Answer (score 0):

C allows variable-length arrays. So after reading the first dimension from the user, you can declare the array with that size.

```
int n;
printf("How big is it? ");
scanf("%d", &n);
int arr[n][M][N];
```

Comment: note that it's only allowed in C99, and optional in C11

Comment: @GRC VLA allow any level of nested array.